# Is it possible to set an attribute using itemId

Tags: javascript, extjs, attributes

I want to create a custom attribute in an override for an input field that is created dynamically.

I am able to create the attribute by setting its parent item with an Id of 'SearchText' like below:

```
Ext.get('TextSearch').select('input').set({'data-selenium-id':  inputId});
```

However I am trying to use best practices and avoid setting Ids all together and rather use its itemId and avoiding any global variables. Any idea?

Comment: Which version of ExtJS are you using?

Comment: @qmat We are using 4.2

Comment: I wold recommend you to use the `.down('#youritemId')` function that Sencha provides for selectors. [link](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.Queryable-method-down)

Comment: @qmat I've tried a few different ways of doing that however it states I cannot use select with component query

Comment: @qmat error is 'Cannot read property 'select' of undefined'

Comment: Are you creating an HTML input field dynamically or an ExtJS component dynamically?

Comment: @Alexander html input field is created upon click of the component field

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a fieldCls  (a special class to the input field)
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.4/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Base-cfg-fieldCls

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    x: 70,
    y: 0,
    width: 130,
    fieldLabel: 'Test',
    fieldCls: 'x-form-field test'
},
Ext.select('.test').set({'data-selenium-id':  inputId});
```